# iOS Swift - Dispatch Group, dispatch async

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a view controller which has few textfields and 4 buttons represent 4 photos that user will click to choose photos to upload to a server, and a Save button. After a photo is picked, I use dispatch_async to upload the photo to the server and get returned URL and I use the URL with other information from the textfields to call another API and upload all that to the server when user clicks Save button.

For this case: if I click Save button but photos haven't uploaded to the server yet, I can use DispatchGroup to notify when all photos are uploaded, and I can show progress hud while waiting and when it's done, I'll call another API to submit all data to the server and pop the current view controller.

But I got a requirement that when users click Save button, the view controller must be popped right away, and all those API calls should be running on the background. The solution that I can think of is when users click Save button, I'll save all textfields information to database (Core Data or UserDefaults). Because I use a PhotoUploading singleton class to upload photo to server, so when the server returns URLs for photos, I'll use that singleton to save these URLs to database as well and call API method to submit all data to the server. But by doing this, I have to put unrelated works for PhotoUploading class.

Is there any better way to do this using GCD & queues and without using database? What I want to archive is to handle everything within this view controller in background using GCD. Something like waiting for uploading task to be done then do this task without blocking the UI

Comment: I do not think that you should use a Database for this. What do you want to store exactly?

Comment: I don't want to use database, that's just 1 solution I can think of to solve the problem

Comment: @HoangTrung, did you deinit the `UIViewController` after dismissing it? If not, what you are asking is completely possible

Comment: deinit? I though when I pop the view controller and I have no reference to it, it will be dellocated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is to do all the tasks in the `UIViewController` even after dismissing it. This is possible by not deinitializing the `UIViewController`. The following is an example in `swift`.

```
var viewController: ViewController?

func launchVC() {

    viewController = ViewController()
    self.present(viewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func dismissVC() {

    if let view_controller = self.viewController {
        view_controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func killVC() {

    viewController = nil
}
```

As you can see above, even after dismissing a `ViewController`, the `ViewController` is still alive. So, whatever task that you started in a background thread in that particular `ViewController` will get completed. When they are done, you can destroy the `ViewController` object.

This is something you can do without using any external `Singleton` class.

Please let me know if you are looking for something else or if you have any doubts in the current solution

Comment: I have a question: if I don't keep a strong reference to the ViewController like this, but create the ViewController instance inside a function & present it inside the function, and when I dismiss it, does the dispatch_async block still running after it's dismissed?

Comment: @Hoang Trung I tried using `Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: )` and a `print` statement after it to see what happens. In both the cases (global and local reference in function), the statement got printed

Comment: @HoangTrung, Thanks for accepting my answer. Can you please upvote if it answered all your queries?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any better way to do this using GCD & queues and without using database?

Depending on the design you have in your project you can have a couple of options:

- Use a `delegate` and pass the data of textfileds through it
- Post an `NSNotification`

Personally I wouldn't create a Database for this

Comment: Using delegate then I have to define a delegate in other viewcontroller which is not possible in my case. Same as posting NSNotification, I have to receive this notification in some other classes which are unknow. I don't want to use AppDelegate or any singleton class to receive NSNotification or to become delegate. What I want to archive is to handle everything within this view controller in background using GCD. Something like waiting for uploading task to be done then do this task without blocking the UI